# NebulaGraph Database: how to find all edges between two types of tags

Tags: nebula-graph

NebulaGraph version is 3.3.1.

Two types of tags are currently created: `player` and `team`. There are multiple players and teams.
It is hoped that the edges between all players and teams can be queried at one time and deleted.

I have tried the match statement:

```
match (v1:player)-[e]-(v2:team) return e limit 3
```

However, the execution error is as follows: -1005: scan vertices or edges need to specify a limit number, or limit number can not push down

Currently no index is created, and the limit statement is used. I don't actually know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

W/O index of `player` or `team` this query is not allowed by design for now(3.3.0), this is due to in theory, the limit clause cannot be pushed down to storage side(it need to fully scan all player or team first), thus to enable such query, we could create index on player or team to enable such query.

Actually this query can be done as it can pushdown limit filter during the storage data scan:

```
MATCH (v:player) RETURN v LIMIT 3
```

this query scans data of player with LIMIT pushed down.

Or

```
MATCH ()-[e]->() RETURN e LIMIT 3
```

this query scans data of all edges with LIMIT pushed down.